# Let's think of a creative name for our chatroom

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat, faq-proposed

I'm hoping we're nearing the end of beta soon, but even if we aren't, our chatroom name is so bland. "Code Golf." Look at all the creative names others have thought up:

- "Root Access" for Super User
- "The DMZ" for Security
- "The Renderfarm" for Blender
- "The Litter Box" for Pets
- "The Hangar" for Aviation
- "You Are Here" for Travel
- "The Water Cooler" for The Workplace
- "The Whiteboard" for Programmers
- etc...

Can we think of a better name for our chatroom?

Only one idea per answer, please. Vote up the ideas that you like!

Comment: may I downvote the suggestions I _don't_ like?

Comment: @Jan Of course, that's how polls on meta work in general.

Comment: *\me casts three downvotes*

Comment: One of the big advantages (for some things, anyway) of the per-site metas is there is no meta-rep (you just use your rep from the main site) so downvoting unpopular suggests is *almost* free of consequence to the recipient.

Comment: _almost_? What is the consequence?

Comment: @JanDvorak Your answer goes down by one vote, I suppose?

Comment: @JanDvorak On the mother meta the question- and answer-bans are enabled (albeit with much looser triggering criteria). I don't know for certain if they are or are not active on the per-site metas, but I didn't want to overstate the situation.

Comment: I'll add here that we don't have to have only one name. We can use one for a while, and when it feels stale choose another one.

Comment: For the nonce I've gone ahead and made it "The Nineteenth Byte". When we're bored of that I suppose we'll use the then highest voted answer not yet used. Or something. I'm not marking this [status-completed] because I think that continued input will help for future name changes.

Comment: I've gone ahead and marked this as status-completed because we never changed it in seven years despite what dmckee said, so I think it's safe to say this is final, lol.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well, the traditional generic name for the country club bar is "the nineteenth hole", which suggests ***The Nineteenth Byte*** or something like that.

Comment: I love this one

Comment: This idea is awesome.

Comment: That name is perfect; it is exactly 19 bytes in size

Comment: I saw the question and immediately thought "The 10011th Hole". We are definitely on the same wavelength. Posted mine as a separate answer, so that voters may choose as they wish.

Comment: "The 19th hole" has a nice ring to it and uses a single metaphor from golf.  "The Nineteenth Byte" is a mixed  metaphor.

Answer (score 15):

How about <strike>**Chat**</strike> **Cht**?

It's the shortest name I could find.

Comment: What about `xt`? :-) (no...)

Comment: @JanDvorak well then how about `​`

Comment: `cg` is shorter :P

Comment: in which case `pcg` fits our favicon better

Comment: Again we see the importance of an objective winning criterion.

Answer (score 12):

The 10011th Hole, riffing on the 19th hole.

@dmckee is here earlier with a riff on the same premise, but I a) arrived at mine independently, and b) rather like the idea of using binary. So you've got options.

Comment: I like this. Very much a programmer version.

Comment: I don't like this. Only `10000` bytes.

Comment: 10011th Hole Grill, perhaps? :D

Comment: I'd personally just prefer the 19th hole without binary.

Answer (score 8):

Hmm.. ***[The Briefing Room](http://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room)*** because we make short (brief) code..? And it's a chat room of course.

Comment: I like this, although it does have a sort of newsy-political feel to it. It made me think if we had a community slogan, it would have to be "Brevity is the soul of bit." http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=hamlet&Act=2&Scene=2&Scope=scene

Answer (score -2):

How about having a Kolmogorov challenge to output the text "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"?

Comment: It doesn't have much redundancy to work with.

Answer (score -4):

Code Hanger

Answer (score -5):

What about `for e!`?  Golf plus code plus short variable name

Answer (score -6):

Going with the "Puzzle" theme, how about ***Cross Words***?

Answer (score -7):

***The Press of Inspiration*** alludes vaguely to the work of squeezing out a few more bytes in code golf