# Why is chat called "The Nineteenth Byte"?

Tags: discussion, chat

Why is the [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) for Programming Puzzles & Code Golf called "The Nineteenth Byte"?

Where did the name come from? Is it a reference to something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the meta thread ["Let's think of a creative name for our chatroom"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1005/2867):

> Well, the traditional generic name for the country club bar is "the nineteenth hole", which suggests The Nineteenth Byte or something like that. -- [dmckee](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1006/2867)

Also:

> That name is perfect; it is exactly 19 bytes in size -- [Justin](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/lets-think-of-a-creative-name-for-our-chatroom#comment3619_1006)