# What should we call Off-Topic TNB?

Tags: discussion, chat

**Voting has closed. The Sand Trap is the winner!**

Since we've decided to [officially recognize](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25191/should-we-officially-recognize-off-topic-tnb) TNB's off-topic room [Off-Topic TNB](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136286/off-topic-tnb), it might be a good time to give it its own name.

We'll do this the same way we [decided](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/lets-think-of-a-creative-name-for-our-chatroom/1006#1006) on TNB's name; post one room name per answer. If you think the current name is the best option, feel free to create an answer with that option.

Answer (score 18):

## The Sand Trap

In case we want another name related to the sport golf. It's off-topic, we've veered off the grass into a sand trap. And once you get really involved in a conversation there, it's hard to leave :P.

One con is that a room called "The Sand Trap" would not be immediately recognizable as the off-topic room for CGCC.

Credit to Ginger for suggesting this in chat.

Answer (score 9):

## Golf Overflow

Joke on Stack Overflow, also because the 19th hole is the one players overflow after the game.

Answer (score 8):

## The 11th pin

The opposite of [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling). The most commonly played bowling variant is 10-pin bowling. Thus the "11th pin" would be a place you go to relax after a intense night of bowling.

(Inspired by Ginger's answer)

Comment: And we can name the trash "The 100th Pin" after Wii Sports-style 100-pin bowling :p

Comment: Ah, so close: `The 11th pin` is 12 characters, not 11. :P

Comment: @DLosc `The11th pin`?

Answer (score 7):

## [The Bowling Green](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61919128#61919128)

It even *sounds* off-topic.

Comment: I think this is a really obscure thing, when you google it you just get the college. Most bowling is not played outdoors.

Answer (score 2):

**The Nth Byte**

Play off “The Nineteenth Byte”, plus being able to be on-(ish) or off topic.

Comment: I guess in this case `n = 12`

Answer (score 1):

## Off-Topic TNB

Simple, descriptive, and it's purpose will be immediately obvious

Answer (score 0):

## The Twentieth Byte

The mods can change their room name, can't they? :P

Answer (score -2):

## The 20th Bytedump

Just... sounds right.